# Why is my mssql table data larger than excel equivalent?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, excel

I have two data files that are 156 MB and 200 MB.
 I did some processing in python such as removing a column and adding a new column.

When I import my data into MSSQL table the size explodes to 1GB+.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong or why it does this? Is there a way I can minimize the size of the MSSQL table?

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: You're using data types that require more space than your data actually requires?

Comment: And of course, the .xlsx files are .zips, so compression might be a big issue here.

Comment: @JamesZ - agreed. Check your data types. If you have set lengths consider using varchars. etc

Comment: @JamesZ, FirebladeDan Thanks for the responses. Is there a way to shrink the size in MSSQL without affecting data integrity?

Comment: If you save your data in a text file from excel, I would assume that's more accurate estimate of how much data you have. Without knowing more, check that you don't have char/nchar fields or numeric / decimal fields with big precision or scale (unless you need it, of course)